# Does NSKeyedUnarchiver still throw exceptions in iOS9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding, nskeyedunarchiver

Consider the following snippet that tries to created an `NSKeyedUnarchiver` from an invalid `NSData` object.

```
NSData *data = [@"foo" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
```

When I run this on an iOS 8.4 simulator, I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException`. On an iOS 9.1 simulator, however, the initializer simply returns `nil`.

However, according do the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/initForReadingWithData:), the method should **always** throw an exception on invalid data.

> This method throws an exception if data is not a valid archive.

Why does it only throw an exception on iOS8 but not on iOS9? Is this new behavior in iOS 9 that was simply not documented yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, confirmed iOS 9 devices ( not sure of simulator ) will throw an exception under certain circumstances.  Here is an example exception which I am currently looking into.

```
NSInvalidArgumentException
Description: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x2d, 0xffffffa4, 0xffffffb3, 0x44, 0xffffffbe, 0xffffff89, 0xffffffcb, 0xffffffcf)
```

Comment: Weird, maybe it's a simulator thing then. I don't get exceptions there.